# Angular2 How to get only one value from ngFor

Tags: angular, ngfor

I am currently getting deep nested json objects from the server and using pipe to parse them.

But it is looping every key even tho I want to get only one value. How could I achieve this?

These are codes

Pipe

import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

```
@Pipe({name: 'keyValues'})
export class KeysPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value, args:string[]) : any {
    let keys = [];
    for (let key in value) {
      keys.push({key: key, value: value[key]});
    }
    return keys;
   }
 }
```

Html template

```
 <div *ngFor="let detail of teaInfo | keyValues">
     <div *ngFor="let basicinfo of detail.value | keyValues">
            <p>School: {{basicinfo.value}}</p>
     </div>
 </div>
```

Result

```
school:example1

school:example2

school:example3

school:example4

school:example5

school:example6
```

I also tried this

```
  <div *ngFor="let detail of teaInfo | keyValues">
         <div *ngFor="let basicinfo of detail.value | keyValues">
                 <p>School: {{basicinfo.value['example2']}}</p>
          </div>
      </div>
```

result

```
 school:

 school:example2

 school:

 school:

 school:

 school:
```

still looping without giving value..

But I just want to get

```
school:example2
```

without looping anything..

Help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might do what you want:

```
<div *ngFor="let basicinfo of detail.value | keyValues | splice:2:1">
```